# Nginx on WHM with many account

Tags: wordpress, nginx, cpanel, whm

I am trying to crack this question for while now and Iam afraid of trying it out.

Would installing Nginx on server with many websites affect them all?

Background: I have host server from Contabo (hosting company in Germany) - this is dedicated server running on WHM - there is about 150 websites on it. Some of these websites are huge and have a lot of traffic everyday. My idea was to install nginx and switch those huge/slow websites to it but I don't want to switch all 150 websites as this would take ages to complete.

What would be best solution in this case?

99% of these websites are Wordpress based.

Comment: Why are you installing Nginx in the first place?  If you think you'll get some sort of magic performance boost, that's unlikely.  The performance issue is Wordpress.  The best you can do is enable some decent caching here.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure I'd put any large sites with a lot of traffic on a single host, and certainly not one with 150 other sites...

Comment: Since you have mentioned that you have more word press sites, the following link will be helpful to speed up you site and reduce the traffic. Here we go :  https://websitesetup.org/how-to-speed-up-wordpress/

Comment: Right, so there is really no benefit.